# (13)Permission denied: access to /wsgi denied, mod_wsgi, CentOs

Tags: apache, python-2.7, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a problem. I have operating system CentOS 5.8 . I have written this configuration in httpd.conf file:

> Listen 85

and at the end of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:85>

ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin irakli2692@hotmail.com

DocumentRoot /home/irakli/www/document

<Directory /home/irakli/www/document>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /home/irakli/www/wsgi-scripts/wsgi.wsgi

<Directory /home/irakli/www/wsgi-scripts>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

selinux is permissive.

here are the directories and the file that apache uses:

>

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache root 4096 Aug  1 10:30 document
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache root 4096 Aug  4 12:32 wsgi-scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 irakli apache 271 Aug  4 12:57 wsgi.wsgi
```

and when I call

> 'server ip':85/wsgi

from browser , there is ip of my server instead of 'server ip', I get message:  (403) Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /wsgi on this server.

and in /var/log/httpd/error.log writes:

> ```
> (13)Permission denied: access to /wsgi denied
> (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
> ```

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A home directory such as '/home/irakli' would itself normally have restrictive permissions such that Apache user cannot see in that directory. It is not enough just to change permissions of where your code is stored, parent directories must also be accessible.

Comment: thanks. I stored the wsgi.wsgi  in the /var/www/html directory and it works